# Trying to make a simple Axios mock with jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am trying to understand [this example](https://stackabuse.com/using-mocks-for-testing-in-javascript-with-jes/), so the first thing I am trying is removing his `axiosConfig.js`, so the example looks more like the current case I would like to solve. However I get this error

```
- Expected
+ Received

  Object {
+   "baseURL": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
    "method": "get",
    "url": "/3/photos?_limit=3",
  },

Number of calls: 1

  39 |         const photos = await getPhotosByAlbumID(3);
  40 |         expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalled();
> 41 |         expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ method: 'get', url: '/3/photos?_limit=3' })
     |                               ^
  42 |         expect(photos.length).toEqual(3);
  43 |         expect(photos[0].albumId).toEqual(3)
  44 |     });
```

## Question

Can anyone figure out how to fix the failed test?

If I remove `baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'` from `getPhotosByAlbumId()`, but it doesn't make sense to have `axios.request()` without a `baseURL`.

I have it online at https://repl.it/@SandraSchlichti/jest-playground#index.js

**index.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getPhotosByAlbumId = async (id) => {
    const result = await axios.request({
      baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
      method: 'get',
      url: `/${id}/photos?_limit=3`
    });
    const { data } = result;
    return data;
};

module.exports = getPhotosByAlbumId;
```

**index.spec.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const getPhotosByAlbumID = require('./index');

jest.mock('axios', () => {
    return {
        baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
        request: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
            data: [
                {
                    albumId: 3,
                    id: 101,
                    title: 'incidunt alias vel enim',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/600/e743b',
                    thumbnailUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/e743b'
                },
                {
                    albumId: 3,
                    id: 102,
                    title: 'eaque iste corporis tempora vero distinctio consequuntur nisi nesciunt',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/600/a393af',
                    thumbnailUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/a393af'
                },
                {
                    albumId: 3,
                    id: 103,
                    title: 'et eius nisi in ut reprehenderit labore eum',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/600/35cedf',
                    thumbnailUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/35cedf'
                }
            ]
        })
    }
})

describe('test getPhotosByAlbumID ', () => {
    afterEach(() => jest.resetAllMocks());

    it('fetches photos by album id', async () => {
        const photos = await getPhotosByAlbumID(3);
        expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ method: 'get', url: '/3/photos?_limit=3' })
        expect(photos.length).toEqual(3);
        expect(photos[0].albumId).toEqual(3)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since in your implementation you're calling `axios.request` with an object that has baseURL, it doesn't matches your assertion.

So you can either assert that it has to be called with an object that has baseURL

```
expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
    method: "get",
    url: "/3/photos?_limit=3",
});
```

or that the object the method has been called with has to have these two properties:

```
expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({ method: "get", url: "/3/photos?_limit=3" })
);
```

[working example](https://repl.it/@StefanTeneff/jest-playground#index.spec.js)

Answer (score 3):

I'll recommend U to use [Asymmetric Matchers](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#asymmetric-jest-matchers)

```
 expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/3/photos?_limit=3'
  }))
```

Sometimes you have a big object and is not necessary to match the exact object you can choose which ones you want to compare.

Another example could be:

```
expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
  postalCode: expect.any(Number)
}));
```

here your example working https://repl.it/join/ldayfmqz-yoandrycollazo